# I have a linux script that runs flawlessly from the command line but refuses to work as a cron

Tags: linux, bash, perl, cron

This script runs when logged in but I cannot get it to work under a cron job, any ideas?

This script is used to monitor a wep page for changes if it detects any graphic/visual differences it has to send an email.

I've read other posts about such problems, and tried to implement some of the suggestions, but I still get errors and even if there are changes I don't get the email. (FYI: The email has been changed for confidentiality purposes)

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
`SHELL=/bin/bash`;
`PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin`;
`cd /root/pagechange`;
`rm -f null`;
`wkhtmltoimage --no-images --height 3000 --javascript-delay 7500 http://www.google.com /root/pagechange/sys.jpg`;
`$dif=/usr/bin/compare -metric AE /root/pagechange/sys.jpg /root/pagechange/sys1.jpg null: 2>&1`;
print "1";
if ( $dif == 0 ) {
  print "They're equal\n";
} else {
   $to = 'me@domain.com';
   $from = 'you@domain.com';
   $subject = 'Page changes detected ';
   $message = "Get to work";
   print "2";
   open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
# Email Header
   print MAIL "To: $to\n";
   print MAIL "From: $from\n";
   print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
# Email Body
   print MAIL $message;
print "3";
   close(MAIL);
   print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
}

print "4";
`cp /root/pagechange/sys.jpg /root/pagechange/sys1.jpg`;
print "5";
#`rm /root/pagechange/index.html`;
exit
```

Comment: Not the solution to your problem by any means but it doesn't look like using Perl is really offering you any advantages. Perhaps one way of solving the problem would be to simply use a shell script.

Comment: Cron sends you mail if it fails. Do you have anything in there? (open a terminal and enter 'mail')

Comment: Well what happens when cron tries to execute the script? What error do you get? We cannot _guess_ that, you have to tell us! Check the log files!

Comment: afaik every backtick command creates a new system call/ a new shell. so the later called ones don't "know" about your previous declared variables. if it was bash you could `#!/usr/bin/bash --login` to exec your profile as if logging in setting your vars "global". don't know if its possible in perl alike. in your case, why don't use a shell-script anyway as you use perl merley just to exec shell commands?

Comment: Errors (logs/stack traces) were meant to be read. Don't start guessing, read the errors.

Comment: When you say this program "works flawlessly", I would probably say "against all odds, it does actually result in something that looks like it is working, but more likely is a combination of luck and lack of good test cases." The line where you try to assign to `$dif` inside a backtick command is just a sign that you are not understanding what you are doing, and if you think that works, it is only because you are not using `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: As @evilive says, you cannot set shell variables with system calls like backticks, `qx()` or `system`, because they open a new shell each time, and when the command ends, this new shell and all its settings are discarded. If this is actually working, it is because your shell already has these variables set somehow. Or you are using a different path and shell than you think. You can however affect the path by setting it in `%ENV`, e.g. `$ENV{PATH} = " ... "`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what that might look like in Perl. I only modified the most obvious problems:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Set the environment with the %ENV hash
# environment variables set in a subshell will not persist
$ENV{SHELL} = '/bin/bash'; # although you don't need this
$ENV{PATH}  = ...;

# change directory
chdir '/root/pagechange' or die "Could not change directory: $!";

# remove a file with unlink
unlink 'null';

# list argument form of system
# this prevents arguments from being treated as special by the shell
# use full path to executable so you know which one you use
system '/path/to/wkhtmltoimage', qw(
    --no-images --height 3000 --javascript-delay 7500 
    http://www.google.com /root/pagechange/sys.jpg
    );

# save the result of the backticks to get the program output
my $dif = `/usr/bin/compare -metric AE /root/pagechange/sys.jpg /root/pagechange/sys1.jpg null: 2>&1`;

print "1";
if ( $dif == 0 ) {
    print "They're equal\n";
    } 
else {
    my $to      = 'me@domain.com';
    my $from    = 'you@domain.com';
    my $subject = 'Page changes detected';
    my $message = "Get to work";

    print "2";
    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    # Email Header
    print MAIL "To: $to\n";
    print MAIL "From: $from\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
    # Email Body
    print MAIL $message;

    print "3";
    if( close(MAIL) ){
        print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
        }
    else { # close puts the error in $? instead of $! (until 5.22!)
        my $error = $? >> 8; 
        print "Problem sending mail: $error";
        }
    }

print "4";
# list argument form of system, again
system '/bin/cp', qw(/root/pagechange/sys.jpg /root/pagechange/sys1.jpg);

print "5";
# unlink '/root/pagechange/index.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides anything else, it has to be:

```
$dif=`/usr/bin/compare -metric AE /root/pagechange/sys.jpg /root/pagechange/sys1.jpg null: 2>&1`;
```

Your not assigning anything to $dif as variable within your script in your code. And whatever you do in the shell your way, it stays in the shell.

edit: That alone surely will not solve your problem, check the other comments

Comment: Incorrect. It will try to interpolate `$dif` in the command, which results in just the empty string. `use warnings` would have caught this and warned about uninitialized variable in concatenation or string. The check afterwards `if ($dif == 0)` gives the illusion of working also because `use warnings` is not used. The warning there would have been `use of uninitialized value in numeric eq`. The result is a false positive, since `undef == 0` is true.

Comment: @TLP Sorry, but why incorrect? Executing in backticks and assigning in scalar context results in having the whole output of the executed command as string assigned to the variable. http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands (your other remarks are right though ;))

Comment: It is incorrect that the command will set `$dif` in the shell. The executed command will be `=/usr/bin/compare -metric ...`, because `$dif` will be interpolated as the empty string `""`. It is as if you did `my $str = "$dif= ...";  qx($str);`. The rest of your answer is correct.

Comment: Thats right, but i didn't meant it that way. I hope I made it clearer above now.